# How to calculate the proper numbers without doing a switch?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need an algorithm to calculate an offset based on an array length. I have manually got the number for each number, but if possible without doing a case/switch.

Given an array length `x`, I need to come up with something that calculates this:

```
20 if x == 5
25 if x == 4
35 if x == 3
50 if x == 2
```

Am I missing something? Do I have to use a switch here?

Comment: Not sure if you'll find that. Those numbers seem to be too random

Comment: try `({ 5:20, 4:25, 3:35, 2:50 })[ x ]`

Comment: What is the logic involved here? You say you "manually got the number for each number". How did you arrive at those numbers? You haven't told us.

Comment: It's an offset to plotting some bars using `chart.js`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A random guess, but how about `105 div x`?

Or maybe `round(20 / x) * 5`?

In fact, since you only gave four cases, there are a lot different methods you can use. But perhaps more importantly is - are there any patterns you could follow that enables your code to make more sense?

Comment: `round(20/x) * 5` makes sense given the context. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At first lets make clear that your mapping function not linear, because for the (linear) x the interval between your function results differ.

To find a non-linear function you need to apply some "more difficult" function [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) (e.g. Lagrange).

My result with this nice [online tool](http://www.solvemymath.com/online_math_calculator/interpolation.php) for the input `[2, 50], [3, 35], [4, 25], [5, 20]` is `(5x^2-55x+190) / 2`.

But to be honest for such few values I would use a switch - it might be more efficient and keeps your code understandable (e.g. if you look at it in a year or so ;-) ).

Hope that helps.

*Jost

Comment: @Ziyao's equation is a lot simpler.

Comment: @Shawn31313 I know, but I pointed to a solution which can be applied to more than four values. (Ok - you have to keep an eye on the error of the interpolation.)

Comment: My answer was just an example of...... a manual "regression". This is definitely more scientific, but that was too fun to not post. +1 still.